# How to treat C/C++ extension diagnostic warning as error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, compiler-warnings

I am using the C/C++ extension for vscode and have the diagnostics/clang-tidy enabled.

However, it underlines diagnostic errors as yellow/warning **even though the resulting code would not compile at all**

For example, designated initializers need to be in the order of their declaration in standard C++.

[image]

this is a warning by clang-tidy, but actually a compiler error.

**How can I treat these warnings as errors and thus underline them as red?**

Edit:
i have tried

```json
    "C_Cpp.codeAnalysis.clangTidy.args": [
        "--extra-arg=-Werror"
    ]
```

but that does not seem to help

Comment: I use Clangd instead of the stock intellisense, and it highlights the things exactly the same way as a compiler (Clang) would, and is configured with the same flags. It includes Clang-tidy too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-warnings-as-errors` option of clang-tidy. Set it in VS Code:

```json
"C_Cpp.codeAnalysis.clangTidy.args": [
  "-warnings-as-errors=clang-diagnostic-*"
]
```